# UNIX Terminal dialog , that supports item selection

Tags: bash, dialog

Is there any "dialog" that running inside a TTY or x-terminal ? I wanted to make some select operation , e.g configure system service , whether or not should it start at boot time.

I'm not planning to use ncurses library myself , it's better to work with bash script.

Expected item selection:

```
---------------------
Item []
Item []
----------------------
```

Use arrow keys to iterate through those items , and use space to alternate selection of current item , i remeber seeing similar things in RedHat , just not so clear of the command and library.

Thanks !

Comment: you need to ask your question better, or this will get closed...

Comment: @Alnitak sorry but what's going wrong here ?

Comment: you need to provide an example of what sort of dialog / input you're expecting.

Comment: @Alnitak , i've updated my question , please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `dialog --checklist` is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

My smenu (https://github.com/p-gen/smenu) tool can do this:

```
R=$(echo "'Item 1'\\n'Item 2'" | smenu -d -T, -l)
echo $R
```

(use the t command to tag/un-tag an item)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is `read`.
Check this: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html

Comment: no it's not read , i wanted some sort of pesudo-graphic dialog